# more than one file type in pysimplegui

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

The documentation defines file_types parameter as Tuple[Tuple[str,str]]
Does it mean that only one tuple possible? And only one filetype?

It does not work for me with two tuples and two extensions and one tuple and a string of extensions.

```
sg.FilesBrowse("COMEDY", file_types= (("mkv","*.mkv"),("avi","*.avi")),initial_folder=comedy_PATH)

sg.FilesBrowse("COMEDY", file_types= (("video files","*.mkv *.avi")),initial_folder=comedy_PATH)

sg.FilesBrowse("COMEDY", file_types= (("video files",".mkv .avi")),initial_folder=comedy_PATH)
```

I don't get errors I get the empty list. With just one extension, it works, as tuple inside a tuple.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comma missed in your file types, it will be `Tuple[str, str]`, not `Tuple[Tuple[str, str]]`

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

type_1 = (
    ("All JPG Files","*.jpg"),
    ("All PNG Files","*.png"),
)
type_2 = (
    ("All Picture Files", "*.jpg *.png"),    # A comma missed in your code
)
type_3 = (
    ("All Picture Files", ".jpg .png"),      # A comma missed in your code
)

layout = [
    [sg.Input(), sg.FilesBrowse(file_types=type_1)],
    [sg.Input(), sg.FilesBrowse(file_types=type_2)],
    [sg.Input(), sg.FilesBrowse(file_types=type_3)],
]
sg.Window('Title', layout).read(close=True)
```

Comment: with comma between the extensions I get the same result. file_types= (("video files","*.mkv, *.avi")). In my code I do not have sg.Input(), I just need to browse file. May be that somehow messes things up?

Comment: I do not see where the comma is missing in my code. What is the difference between what you have written type_2 = (("All Picture Files", "*.jpg *.png")), and one of my lines. file_types= (("video files","*.mkv *.avi"))

Comment: Check exactly where a comma missed !  type_2 = (("All Picture Files", ".jpg *.png")`,`)